# How to insert dynamic number of columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this is my current code:

for ($i=($loop1-($count-1)); $i <=$loop1 ; $i++)

```
{ 
    ${'track_' . $i}=$_POST['marks'.$i];
     $in="insert into s_101483011(q".($i-20).") value('".${'track_' . $i}."')";
     $inq=mysqli_query($db,$in);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure that you set default values for the columns in case of not mentioning them in the insert query.

For the dynamic part, you can create a map object and generate sql sentence by using that map object that is expected to contain column and corresponding value.

Comment: sorry sir , i did'nt get u ,i was trying to do insert  query  to insert dynamic no. of columns in table according to a count.For eg. like if count is 3 i want to insert 3 cols and leave the rest .i have total of 10 cols .I am a beginner i hope you got me

Comment: Could you please share your table's description? use _desc yourTableName_ command on mysql.